# How to wp_enqueue_script jQuery inside a Plugin

Tags: jquery

I would like to use jQuery in my Wordpress plugin. I'm trying to load the jquery library using the enqueue script but its throwing an error.

*Error: $ is not a function*

Here's the code snippet that's inside my main plugin.php file...

```
function ($post)
{
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function doTestParse(searchString){
        var rx = new RegExp('(?![^<]+>)'+searchString, "gi");
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(rx, '<b>$&</b>'));
    }
    </script>
<?php ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery is included in [`noConflict` mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) in WordPress, so you can't use the shorthand `$`, but must write `jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).html().replace(rx, '<b>$&</b>'));`

Comment: Thanks Jan, does <b>$&</b> become <b>jQuery&</b> ?

Comment: @Scott: `html()` returns a Javascript `String` object, and `replace()` is a standard function. [`&$` means "the matched substring"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) in this context, so the `$` has nothing to do with jQuery and has to stay.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure when exactly your code fires, but it is good practice to add enqueue directives to `init` hook, instead of trying to call them in-place.

[`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) docs in Codex have plenty of useful examples on topic.